# versions of jetty-util-ajax, hadoop-azure, azure-storage for spark-3.2.4. what are the compatible versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

i'm having problem on getting the right versions that are compatible with each other am running spark 3.2.4 now, i downgraded from spark-3.4.0 cause i couldn't find the right one. i'd be happy if i get for both versions either.

i tried to run jetty-util-ajax, hadoop-azure, azure-storage with spark3.2.4 on IDE and run in to error with  the right dependencies and libraries.